# How can I encrypt dll so it's code won't be visible in Reflector?

Tags: c#, .net, reflector

How can I encrypt dll so its code **won't** be visible in Reflector?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+obfuscation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to prevent dll from being opened in a software like reflector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862560/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-dll-from-being-opened-in-a-software-like-reflector)

Comment: (closed as there isn't a specific question here, and ***lots*** of existing referece questions)

Comment: Looks like it's closed because what's being asked is impossible. But it seems to me the question itself is fine.

Comment: thank you. sorry for didnt see

Comment: If you encrypted it, how would the computer run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always **obfuscate** your code to make it **harder** to understand, but never encrypt it at all.

Google for "dot net obfuscator".